# Traefik ipwhitelist middleware example for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm having trouble putting using Traefik's IPWhitelist middleware in my kubernetes (1.14) cluster.

I'm using the DaemonSet config from here:

```
https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/
```

I'd like to apply this whitelist to all traffic in/out of the cluster.

- Howto apply to all traffic?
- Can I use an annotation instead of an IngressRoute?
- Is there an example or documentation I missed?

Thank you!

Here's what I have so far:

```
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: middlewares.traefik.containo.us
spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: Middleware
    plural: middlewares
    singular: middleware
  scope: Namespaced
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-whitelist
spec:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange:
    - 2400:cb00::/32
    ...
    - 131.0.72.0/22
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: allup
  annotations:
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: cloudflare-tls-cert
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: app-www-service
              servicePort: http
    - host: stuff.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: app-stuff-service
              servicePort: http
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-whitelist
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web  # <- what is this for?
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`)  # <- Howto apply to all ingress?
      kind: Rule
      middlewares:
        - name: cloudflare-whitelist
    - match: Host(`stuff.example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      middlewares:
        - name: cloudflare-whitelist
```

- Howto apply to all traffic?
- Can I use an annotation instead of an IngressRoute?
- Is there an example or documentation I missed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I found, from the helpful peeps on Traefik Slack.  The code above is for Traefik v2.0 which is still in Alpha.

For Traefik 1.7 (the [current release](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik) referenced in the [Kubernetes Guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#deploy-traefik-using-a-deployment-or-daemonset) as I write this)

For 1.7, use regular [annotations](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#general-annotations)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: allup
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "2400:cb00::/32, 2606:4700::/32, 2803:f800::/32, 2405:b500::/32, 2405:8100::/32, 2a06:98c0::/29, 2c0f:f248::/32, 173.245.48.0/20, 103.21.244.0/22, 103.22.200.0/22, 103.31.4.0/22, 141.101.64.0/18, 108.162.192.0/18, 190.93.240.0/20, 188.114.96.0/20, 197.234.240.0/22, 198.41.128.0/17, 162.158.0.0/15, 104.16.0.0/12, 172.64.0.0/13, 131.0.72.0/22"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: cloudflare-tls-cert
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: app-www-service
              servicePort: http
```